# Use HQL query in JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, hql

In proces of converting an old SOAP webservice to REST with spring boot, the query I need converted is in a hbm.xml file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<query name="Team.getByFactoryWithTeam">
    select distinct t
    from Team t
    inner join t.workstations as w
    inner join w.area as a
    inner join a.factory as f
    where f.factoryName = :factoryName
    and t.teamName is not null
    order by t.name
</query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried to fit it in my `@NamedQuery`of my JPA Entity

The Team Class is

```
public class Team {
private String name;
private String teamName;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "teams")
@OrderBy
private SortedSet<Workstation> workstations;
//getters and so on

public class Workstation{
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "WORKSTATION_TEAM",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "WORKSTATION_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_ID")
)
private Set<Team> teams;
}
```

And got a StackOverflow when running the query

```
    2018-04-25 16:51:04.934  WARN 25944 --- [io-30001-exec-4]  o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@587dfff7<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@248116732 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@2b78205c>
2018-04-25 16:51:04.937 ERROR 25944 --- [io-30001-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.<init>(CharBuffer.java:281) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? This looks like perfectly valid JPQL. You should be able to use it as a named query.

Comment: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null, I believe it comes from my manytomany mapping

Comment: Please post your attempt at putting the query in a `@NamedQuery` annotation, the way you tried calling the query, and the full stack trace, if available

Comment: Moved it to my RepositoryRestResource as an @Query anotation I'll add a part of it up top

Comment: Are you sure this is a JPA problem? `@RepositoryRestResource` will obviously try to serialize the results into JSON/XML, and `StackOverflowError` wouldn't surprise me, as neither side of the relationship is marked to be ignored by the serialization. You'll need to mark one side as ignored (using `@XmlTransient`, `@JsonIgnore` or whatever your serialization library provides)

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow, I have multiple mappings done already and have used @JsonIgnore a couple of times so I'll add them with every many to many.